# Apache 2 running even when stopped

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-14.04, tomcat8

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on my VPS, and I'm trying to run Apache Tomcat on port 80.

So, I changed the Apache2 ports.conf (and the default.conf in sites-enabled) to a different port, and server.xml for tomcat to point to port 80.

However, many a times, I get the default Apache2 page on port 80 (even after disabling the default site and even deleting index.html from /var/www/html). Refreshing a few times helped earlier, but starting today, that didn't help. So, I stopped the Apache2 service and yet, it still shows up.

Tomcat is showing up when trying to access the site with the IP address or with http://www.nurvsofsteel.com, but not with the domain name: http://nurvsofsteel.com

Please help...

Comment: Try pressing `Shift`+`F5` to clear cache and reload

Comment: I did! :(
But it doesn't work either. I just noticed another strange thing. It works if I add www. to the domain name, but it doesn't work when the www is not there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found that it was actually Nginx that was running on port 80 and picking up the Apache default page! [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/642288/705737) post helped figure it out.

In your case, it might actually be Tomcat running on port 80 but just showing a different default page. Try running `sudo netstat -l4np` to check which process is listening at port 80

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the problem. I had accidentally edited the /etc/hosts in my local machine instead of on the VPS (both the usernames were same, and I'd forgotten that I was logged in to the VPS from another tab in my terminal).